# array and point problem

Tags: c

Here, I have a bad program. Its outputs confusing me, anyone can tell me why ?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main()
 {
    int i = 0;
    char *a_result[10];
    char *b_result[10];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char a_array[10];
        char *b_array = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
        int j = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            a_array[j] = 'a' + i;
            b_array[j] = 'a' + i;
        }
        a_array[j] = '\0';
        b_array[j] = '\0';
        a_result[i] = a_array;
        b_result[i] = b_array;

    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("a_result: %s b_result: %s\n",a_result[i],b_result[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

I think the a_result and b_result should be the same, but it is not.

Here is the output on my computer.

```
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: aaaaaaaaa
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: bbbbbbbbb
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: ccccccccc
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: ddddddddd
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: eeeeeeeee
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: fffffffff
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: ggggggggg
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: hhhhhhhhh
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: iiiiiiiii
a_result: jjjjjjjjj b_result: jjjjjjjjj
```

any explanation about this is appreciate!

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    char a_array[10];
    ...
    a_result[i] = a_array;
}
```

You are declaring an array on stack in the `for` loop's scope. This means the array will become invalid once you leave the for loop. That is, the stuff inside `a_result` is invalid.

For on-stack vairables, the compiler will reuse the same memory area for `a_array` in every loop (which is not for `b_array` since a fresh memory will be received from heap by `malloc`). Hence for your case, `a_result` just has 10 copied of the same invalid pointer.

---

If you want a copy of the content that array, make the type of `a_result` to be

```
char a_result[10][10];
```

and use

```
memcpy(a_result[i], a_array, sizeof(a_result[i]));
```

to copy into the result.

Comment: Oh, I get it. I should copy the  value of a_array at ervery loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're continually writing over an array (`a_array`) at the same position, then storing the address into `a_result[i]` (`a_result` is an array of pointers).  Thus, at the end, every element of `a_result` contains an identical address (of `a_array`), and `a_array` itself has the values written by the last iteration.

Worse, accessing the contents of `a_array` (including through the pointers in `a_result`) outside the for loop is undefined behavior.  That storage can only be used within the loop body.

In contrast, you're allocating new heap memory for `b_array` (which is not in fact an array) every iteration, and storing this (new) pointer into `b_result`.  Thus, you don't overwrite old values.

Comment: Yeah ,I know each element of a_result is same. But Why ?

I think I get a new a_array in ervery loop.

Answer (score 0):

The array

```
 char a_array[10];
```

goes out of scope at the end of every loop iteration and is then effectively recreated at the same memory location. You end up with a bunch of pointers pointing to the last re-creation, which contains the "jjjjjj" string.